# Implementing my own Lens in Panda3D

Tags: c++, python, panda3d

## Background

I'm trying to implement a highly non-linear lens to do lens distortion in Panda3D for a complex projection setup.  I want to use this implementation following [this approach](https://www.panda3d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=9500).

## The question

Can I do it in Python (and if so, how, what am I doing wrong) or do I have to do it in C++ (and if so, where do I start)?

## Attempts so far

I've tried subclassing [Lens](https://www.panda3d.org/reference/1.7.2/python/classpanda3d.core.Lens.php), but if I let my subclass call the super constructor (or don't override the constructor at all), I get an error:

```
>>> from panda3d.core import Lens
>>> class MyLens(Lens):
...    def __init__(self):
...       super(MyLens,self).__init__()
... 
>>> l = MyLens()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in __init__
TypeError: Error Can Not Init Constant Class (Lens)
```

If I don't call the super constructor, the class `isinstance(Lens)`, but not recognized as such by Panda3D code:

```
fcamNode = Camera('fcam')
flens = MyLens.MyLens()
assert isinstance(flens, Lens)
fcamNode.setLens(flens)
```

results in `TypeError: LensNode.set_lens() argument 1 must be Lens, not MyLens`.

If I subclass `PerspectiveLens` instead, I **can** call the super constructor and pass instances of my class to `setLens()`, but none of its overridden methods are ever called and the rendered scene looks like it was rendered with the stock `PerspectiveLens`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is all coded in C++, i.e. the `Lens` class is internally a C++ class and all the other classes are also C++ classes which overload the C++ `Lens` class.

If you overload such Python-wrapped class and pass that object down to some C++ code again, the C++ code wont recognize the Python overwriting.

You might be able to write a C++ `Lens` superclass which is able to do that, i.e. which implements all possible virtual functions and in all cases, always looks up wether there is a related Python object attribute which can be called. Note that this is likely to be slow.

---

In C++, you find the definition of `Lens` [here](https://www.panda3d.org/reference/1.8.1/cxx/classLens.php) and [here](https://www.panda3d.org/reference/1.8.1/cxx/lens.h_source.php).

Take a look at the `FisheyeLens` [here](https://www.panda3d.org/reference/1.8.1/cxx/fisheyeLens.h_source.php) to see what functions you have to overwrite from `Lens`.

Comment: Thanks, this answers half of my question.  I'll accept the first answer giving me just a hint at where to start implementing a custom Lens in C++, since that was part of my original question. (Of course I'll also look into that myself as soon as I get the chance, and get back here, update, and accept accordingly)

Comment: [This](https://www.panda3d.org/manual/index.php/Subclassing) and [this](http://panda3d.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/panda3d/doc/INSTALL-MK?view=markup) covers the subject.  I'm wondering if I can build (and distribute) a `Lens` (Python and C++) without the the whole project, though.

Comment: Have you implemented a new Lens object? Do you have the code somewhere available?